# cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket plugin throw chrome undefine Error

Tags: android, cordova, sockets, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I create ionic 3 application and I want send and receive data between two app with hotspot network and I try to create client and server socket on each app with this plugin :

```
npm i cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket
```

and try with this code :

```
declare var chrome;
```

and use plugin in ionViewDidLoad :

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){

    chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, createInfo => {
      let socketTcpId = createInfo.socketId;
       chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketTcpId, "127.0.0.1", 12345, result => {
         console.log("Connected to server");
       });
    });
  }
```

and run :

```
ionic cordova build android
```

and install and run apk file on genymotion but console give me this error :

```
chrome is not defined
```

and also I try with this way :

ionViewDidLoad(){

```
(<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, createInfo => {
  socketTcpId = createInfo.socketId;
   chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketTcpId, "127.0.0.1", 12345, result => {
    console.log("Connected to server");
   });
});
```

}

but console give me last error

Comment: is the app working fine in Real device or only genymotion ?

Comment: I test app only on genymotion and give me  chrome not defined error in chrome inspect

Comment: instead user this library cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp

Answer (score 0):

You need to install following TCP library

```
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp
```